# displaying image from folder in MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, linq

I have a `Pictures` column in the database where I store a Path to an image's folder. Several images are located there and I want to display only one of them (let's say first one in the list).

I'm doing something like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/36pMp.png

I've tried to display it this way in the View:

```
<img src="@Url.Content(@item.Pictures)" width="50" height="60" >
```

I should write the exact file path in the database (eg. `~\Pictures\Nexus 5\001.jpg`) for the code to work but I need the folder path because I have to display other images on another page.

This is what my code looks like:

**models:**

```
namespace SmartPhoneCatalog.Models
{
    public partial class Products
    {
        [Key]
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        //...
        public string Pictures { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace SmartPhoneCatalog.Models
{
    public partial class PhonesDB : DbContext
    {
        public PhonesDB()
            : base("name=DefaultConnection")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }

        public DbSet<Products> ProductList { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
namespace SmartPhoneCatalog.Controllers {
    public class HomeController : Controller {
        PhonesDB _db = new PhonesDB();

        public ActionResult Index() {
            var model =
                from p in _db.ProductList
                orderby p.Price descending
                select p;

            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: So do you mean that the Pictures column contains '~/Pictures/Nexus 5' and this view needs to find and display the first image in that folder (e.g. 001.jpg)? Then other views show all the images in the folder?

Comment: yes, exactly as you said.

Comment: that didn't help `<img src="@item.Pictures" alt="@item.Name" />`